# iPhone - Safari parent window focus issue

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, window, focus

I am having a peculiar problem with a website i am developing. The problem *only* happens on the iPhone(safari).

My setup is as follows.

1) I have a CLIENT page - shows an initial page, and has a login button.

2) User clicks on the LOGIN button, and is shown a LOGIN popup/new-window  (this is created by posting a form using jquery 'submit' function with target='_blank')

CLIENT.html

```
var formData = '<form style="display: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-width: 0; overflow: hidden;" id="MyFormId" action="https://MYSERVER.COM/v2/widgets" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="connect"/><input type="hidden" name="referringURL" value="http://MYCLIENT.com/ClientPage.html"/><input type="hidden" name="cartOwnerId" value="A2R6QUFKT17A1O"/></form>';


jQuery("#"+this.getLocation()).append(formData);


jQuery("#"+formIdName).submit();
```

3) User enters credentials on LOGIN window, and submits. A call is made to the SERVER to authenticate. On SUCCESSFUL authentication, we want to

- CLOSE the LOGIN window
- REDIRECT Client page to new URL

4) Everything works as planned, EXCEPT that the Client window (that created the LOGIN popup/new window), does not return to full-screen (after the LOGIN window closed).

If i try to put a window.opener.focus() in the LOGIN page javascript, i get focus on the CLIENT page, but the LOGIN page does not close(even if i put window.close before the window.opener.focus())

```
LOGIN html
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  ...

    window.close();

    window.opener.focus()
});
```

Is there any tips on how i can close the LOGIN window, and redirect the client page to a new URL, and make the Client window full screen?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this work:

In opener:

```
window.closePopup = function () {
  window.popup.close();
  window.focus();
}
// open login popup
window.popup = window.open(...);
```

After user logs in in popup window:

```
window.opener.closePopup();
```

THat is, don't have a window close itself, but have the opener close the popup. I've tried something like this and it seems to work *sometimes*... I haven't quite been able to isolate why it doesn't work. I know one thing that happens in my case is that the user has to interact with the popup window in order for the `window.opener.closePopup()` to work...